# How to copy individual value combinations from three columns to a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a beginner so bear with me

The code I'm using now is this, given to me by user "Xabier", slightly edited by me. This copies the rows with a certain document# into a separate sheet, thus giving me a list:

[image: how the original list might look]

```
Sub foo()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("inbd")
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet: Set wsDestination = Sheets("test")

    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Range("A1:N" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets("test").Cells(1, 26).Value

    ws.Range("A2:N2" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    DestinationRow = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    wsDestination.Range("A" & DestinationRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ws.Range("A1:N" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1

End Sub
```

Now what I want to do is create something like a header for the document containing data regarding the origin of the imports.

This data is the "Import#", "Invoice#", "Supplier" and "Invoice date". Basically for every unique Invoice# I need to create a unique entry even if the supplier or the import# is the same.

And I can't copy the entire row, I just need to copy certain cells in each row.
After I actually figure out how all this works, this is how the document is going to look.

[image: The final document look]

Comment: Hello Joe and welcome to Stackoverflow - Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - especially https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Meaning: Show us your code and we will help you.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51659855/3233363

Answer (score 0):

this is actually a pretty involved solution that StackOverflow is not meant for. Instead, i'll give you an idea of how you could implement this yourself.

```
loop through filtered data
    if not first loop, check if the previous new sheet's invoice number matches this one
        check that new sheet is not too full to add invoice
            copy this row's invoice information to new sheet
```

[looping through filtered data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10850002/2727437)

[copying data from cell to cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23668300/2727437)

Comment: I found a solution using the advanced filter. this is how the macro looks for it

     Sub Macro3()
     '
     ' Macro3 Macro
     '

    '
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("B:B").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
    End Sub